# Can't install mlabwrap in Windows

Tags: python, mlabwrap

I typed `python setup.py install` in Windows cmd.exe, but I got error like this

```
WINDOWS SPECIFIC ISSUE? Unable to remove c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\tpxs79tx;
please delete it manually
[Error 32] : 'c:\\users\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpxs79tx'

running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'mlabraw' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Try a different compiler, http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266.

Comment: Could google around first though

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat